# How can I access a database on a docker image that I've launched using docker-compose up?

Tags: docker

How can I access a db in a docker image that I've run `docker-compose up` on?

In the docker compose file I have:

```
  metadata-db:
    image: fastdb #${ECR}/bmll/sampledb:latest
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: fastdb.dockerfile
    networks:
      - dd-internal
    ports:
      - 5577:5432
```

And I have successfully launched the docker image with `docker-compose up`.

However, now I would like to access the above `metadata-db`, but I'm not sure how I can do this- any suggestions?

Comment: Through port 5577 on the host.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, my understanding is to run something like: 
`psql -h <host-> -p 5577 -U bmlltech -d metadata`

Comment: How can I find out what the host it?

Comment: `psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5577 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.`

Comment: Are you sure the image is running a PostgreSQL server, and it's configured to listen on 0.0.0.0:5432?  What is in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The `port` field in the yaml translates as if you were running a container with the `-p` option so in your case that'd be `-p 5577:5432` meaning your mapping the port 5577 on your host to the container port 5432.

tl;dr `http://localhost:5577`

Comment: `psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5577 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.`

Comment: Yeah I mean it depends what you're trying to do, what that image is and what not. The question was just how to reach it, not really how to interact with it. `http` was just one option to make clear which address to use. I don't think it actually accepts connections over http.

Comment: thanks @Rick Racow. I am trying to connect to the database. 

I tried something like this: `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5577 -U some_username -d metadata-db`

Comment: I know that it is possible to connect to the db using psql, but I somehow get the above error

Comment: The problem here is that we can't test/replicate because we don't have the image. we also don't know what kind of db is actually running there with what kind of configuration